# Replace generic string with something else in python

Tags: python, replace

I basically have strings that might be like this

```
str1 = "Z (X) Z"
str2 = "Z .X. Z"
str3 = "Z 'X' Z"
```

The X might be anything, as well as Z: for example:

```
str1 = "(example1)         "
str2 = "random_stuff .example2. other_random_stuff"
str3 = "'example3' stuff"
```

What I need is to replace the X with something else, but how can I do that if the X could be anything? I have to extrapolate the portion of string delimited by "..", "()", "''" (the X portion) and replace it with something else. Z portions can be anything as well and they should not be considered, and the X thing can be found in the middle of the string as well so i cant use this:

```
str1 = ".X."
str_to_be_changed = str1[1][-1]
str1.replace(str_to_be_changed, "Y")
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expressions?

Comment: `re.sub(r"[(.']([^).']*?)[).']", "foo", str1)`?

Comment: why do you need to replace anything at all? just check what the first/last characters are and build the new string by wrapping Y with those characters. unless your actual examples are more complicated then you are letting on?

Comment: @aplassard, not really, going to check out some

Comment: Hrmz, this is complicated by the fact that you have an opener that isn't equal to the closer (`(` vs. `)`) here.

Comment: I would trivially `str1 = str1[0] + 'Y' + str1[-1]`, assuming the delimiter is only one character. (if not, please add details to your example)

Comment: @devnull Note that the examples all expect paired delimiters, e.g. I don't think `(X.` should match the regex.

Comment: @njzk2, it isn't. str1 could also be like `str1 ="random stuff (X) other stuff"` so I have to take just the portion of code delimited by the ().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use a regular expression with a replacement function:

```
import re

def change_string(string, replacement):
    def repl(match):
        o, c = match.group('open'), match.group('close')
        if o + c in ('..', "''", '()'):
            return '{}{}{}'.format(o, replacement, c)
        return match.group(0)
    return re.sub(r"(?P<open>['.(]).*?(?P<close>['.)])", repl, string)
```

The `repl()` function verifies that the opener and closing characters match up before replacing.

Demo:

```
>>> str1 = ".X."
>>> change_string(str1, 'Y')
'.Y.'
>>> change_string("This is a larger 'example' with (more than one) replacement, including a 'false positive.", 'Y')
"This is a larger 'Y' with (Y) replacement, including a 'false positive."
```

Comment: Brilliant! That seems to be what I'm looking for. I'll give a try, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `str.format()`

For example:

```
l = ".{}."
print l.format("mything")
'.mything.'
```

Comment: That presumes you know what `X` is going to be.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, going by the examples, it could be as simple as ```str1 = str1[0] + 'Y' + str1[-1]``` as was suggested above

Comment: @wnnmaw: there are easier ways to remove the first and last character of a string. But that's the point, it is *not* that simple.

Comment: true, if you are not making the string, this isn't useful